# Put Rest webservices with just one parameter

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, put

I am using Java and Jersey for my REST web services. I want to have a `put` method that takes just one integer value. From this integer value I can then use business logic to update my database. Usually I am passing a custom [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) from my PUT as they often contain more than one piece of information. It seems a bit wasteful creating a custom DTO for just one value. Is it possible to pass this variable as a @PathParam with a PUT

I have tried

```
@PUT
@Path("apple/{pearId}")
public void doStuff(@PathParam("pearId") Integer pearId) {...}
```

but this does not work if I pass in

```
http://myurl/apple/123
```

I tried using REST client to PUT this but end up with a `HTTP Status 403`

Can I pass a variable as a PUT @PathParam?

Thanks

**UPDATE: more details on error**

The error is from REST Client

```
HTTP Status 403 -
type Status report
message
   descriptionAccess to the specified resource () has been forbidden
```

I will add logging now to see if I actually get into the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use @PathParam with a PUT. HTTP 403 means [Forbidden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403). This error is probably not coming from Jersey. Where is that error coming from? Does your code throw that error?

Comment: Unfortunately I have just updated my code and it's broken now. I will get back to you.. thanks for your help so far

Comment: Thanks @Oleksi. Letting me know that the PUT was valid was important. I managed to debug and there was a problem in my code. Not the interaction with the web services. Thanks again